# C# datagridview column into an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, datagridview

I am building a program with c#, and have included a datagridview component into it. The datagridview has a fixed amount of columns (2), which I want to save into two separate arrays. The amount of rows does change though. How could I do this?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming a DataGridView named dataGridView1 and you want to copy the contents of the first two columns into Arrays of strings, you can do something like this:

```
string[] column0Array = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
string[] column1Array = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

int i = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    column0Array[i] = row.Cells[0].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
    column1Array[i] = row.Cells[1].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: @Abe of course if he was using .NET 2.0+ we'd recommend using List<T> rather than an Array or ArrayList.

Comment: True on my side, but I was under the impression that if you know the length of your collection before hand that is generally better/more efficient to use an Array (though the performance gain may not be noticeable).

Comment: Um, I don't know if this is a newbie mistake, I am quite new to c#, but this is giving me a NullReferenceException on the column0Array[i]... line when I try to run it.

Comment: @Xedfire Ah, the cell that's throwing that exception probably has a null value.  I updated the code to handle this situation.  In case the ?: operator looks new, check this: [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: @Jay Wouldn't it _have_ to be .NET 2.0+ if he's using a DataGridView? That wasn't introduced until .NET 2.0...

Comment: @Joel You're right, it would be NET 2.0+.  It's funny I missed that because everytime I see here on SO someone say 'GridView' when they mean 'DGV' I fight the urge to edit or correct them!  But as Abe points out, it probably is best the OP use an Array rather then a List<T>.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for the confusion everyone.

Comment: @Xedfire No confusion - my answer would be the same regardless of the Framework version.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ArrayList col1Items = new ArrayList();
ArrayList col2Items = new ArrayList();

foreach(DataGridViewRow dr in dgv_Data.Rows)
{
  col1Items.Add(dr.Cells[0].Value);
  col2Items.Add(dr.Cells[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: After first getting the error when using Jay's code, I tried this out - and it did actually work. But, if you say that Jay's is more efficient, I'll probably keep experimenting!

Answer (score 3):

I used Jay's example and changed it to store all the rows in a single array for easy exporting.
At the end you can easily use LogArray[0,0] to get the string from cell 0, column 0.

```
        // create array big enough for all the rows and columns in the grid
        string[,] LogArray = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            while (x < dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
            {
                LogArray[i, x] = row.Cells[x].Value != null ? row.Cells[x].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                x++;
            }

            x = 0;
            i++; //next row
        }
```

I hope i helped someone with this, its my first time posting any code online, ever. Also i haven't coded in ages just getting started again.