# Read column from dataGridView and place it in a string array

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, arrays

I have a DatagridView in which the first column is fixed and has TextBoxes. The second column has ComboBoxes. All of the rows at the second column have 4 choices(name, surname, address, date).

When the user chooses from the ComboBoxes and presses a button, I need to take the values of the second column and put them in a new `string[]`.

So if the user chooses :

```
name,
surname,
name,
date,
```

They are put in a string array named `FromDataGrid[]`. As far as now I have made this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string[] colB = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# datagridview column into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585740/c-datagridview-column-into-an-array)

Comment: kak ylia's answer is more simple. But not big difference.

Comment: if Kak Ylia's answer works for you, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: @david Of course I will mark it as accepted. But I am waiting him to accept my edit. It says "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed."

Comment: ah sorry, didn't notice that there was a pending edit.

Comment: I'll leave it up to Kak to accept or reject the edit but will say that in my opinion Jay Riggs's answer using the foreach and the conditional operator is clearer and more idiomatic c#. Also using the Convert.ToString will give you null values within the string array, which can lead to unexpected bugs downstream if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    colB[i] = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
```