# DataGridView Column Data to Array

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to transfer all data from a `DataGridView` column to `string[] array` ?

Here is my code so far, unfortunately, it can't convert `DataGridViewRow` to `int`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvrows in dgvDetail.Rows)
{
   array[dgvrows] = dgvDetail.Rows[dgvrows].Cell[3].value.ToString().Trim;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read column from dataGridView and place it in a string array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828010/read-column-from-datagridview-and-place-it-in-a-string-array)

Comment: Are you working with WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in various ways:

- Use a normal `for`-loop. The `foreach` is only syntactic sugar, the real work is always done with the good old for-loop.
- Use `foreach` and the `DataGridViewRow.Index` property to set the array index.
- Use `LINQ` to create the array

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvDetail.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    array[i] = dgvDetail.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim();
}   


foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDetail.Rows) 
{
    array[row.Index] = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim();
}


var array = dgvDetail.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(x => x.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim())
    .ToArray();
```

Note that in both loops you need to initialize the array first!

Comment: `row.Cell` => `row.Cells`