# Remove an item from arraylist as a current row is selected in Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, datagridview

This is what I tried:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.DataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{
    int index = item.Index;
    MessageBox.Show("Index is: " + index);
    ListOfPeople.RemoveAt(item.Index);
}
```

`ListOfPeople` as the ArrayList name

When I delete a row from the datagridview, the row is deleting but the item in the ArrayList is still remaining there. How can I fix that? Maybe refreshing the list could fix the problem?

Comment: What is `item` (item from an ArrayList?) and what is `ListOfPeople` (an ArrayList)?

Comment: @RoiDanton them `item` from `foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.DataGridView2.SelectedRows)`. The ListOfPeople is the ArrayList.

Comment: Please give a better context of what you are doing. Are you working in WPF? You are saying you are deleting something but I only see you remove items out of the ListOfPeople, no idea how this is binding to the DataGridView...

Comment: Fixed my problem with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605223/datagridview-column-data-to-array/33607201#33607201).