# Possible way to do to with foreach instead of for

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

I am trying to convert `DataGridView` columns into an `ArrayList`. I would like to make this code into a `foreach` version. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605223/datagridview-column-data-to-array) answer but, it doesn't worked for me. With this `for` method my problem is, when I am deleting a bunch of rows from the datagridview, then it gives an error or my binary search doesn't work well. That's why I want to try with `foreach` method.

---

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ListOfPeople[i] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Comment: Show your attempt with `foreach` and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: The code in that example is wrong by the way. There's a syntax error in `DataGridView Row row`

Comment: Where/how are you deleting the rows? With `foreach` the enumeration (i.e `dataGridView2.Rows` cannot be changed, by the way

Comment: _"With this for method my problem is, when I am deleting a bunch of rows from the datagridview, then it gives an error or my binary search doesn't work well."_ - so that's your actual problem. What error do you get?

Comment: Non of these answers are helped but I fixed my problem. I removed `ArrayList.sort();` and I used `ArrayList.ToArray();` instead. Now it's perfectly working!

Comment: I get these error message `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
` if I delete a lot from the datagridview,

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to loops you can try *query* `dataGridView2.Rows` with a help of *Linq* and build `ListOfPeople` in one go:

```
 // ArrayList is an obsolete class; let's use List<string>
 List<string> ListOfPeople = dataGridView2
    .Rows
    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `foreach` likewise for any other collection

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    { // code here 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the conversion of `for` to `foreach` is what to do with loop index `i`. Two situations are possible - when you need `i`, and when you don't need `i`.

When `i` is necessary, use `Select` that passes the index to you, like this:

```
foreach (var p in dataGridView2.Rows.Select((r, i) => new {Row = (DataGridViewRow)r, Index = i}) {
    ListOfPeople[p.Index] = p.Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
}
```

When `i` is not necessary, you can use "straight" `foreach`, or even drop the loop altogether:

```
ListOfPeople = dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => r.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The old-school answer to your question (how to use a `foreach` instead of `for`) is pretty close to what @Rahul describes.  However, the Rows collection was a pre-generic collection (i.e., it's been there since .NET v1.x), and when you foreach over it, you get objects, and not rows.  Instead, this works:

```
foreach (var row in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
{ // code here 
}
```

The old school way of keeping track of an index variable (`i`) is something like:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var row in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
{ 
    // your code here 
    ++i;
}
```