# Selecting in arrays the elements from a column of a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 2 columns, with 150 datas => 150 rows.

What I want to do is to manage to take all the values from the 1st column and adding them into an array, like this

```
for ( int i=1; i<150; i++) 
    array[i] = ..... ?! .... ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# datagridview column into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585740/c-sharp-datagridview-column-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is Windows Forms DataGridView you can use :-

```
for ( int i=1; i<150; i++) 
  array[i] = MyDataGridView[1,i].value ;
or
  array[i]=  MyDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
```